# Dropbox icon missing in Loki

Tags: wingpanel, icons, dropbox

I got a red circle with a crossed red line instead of Dropbox icon.

Answer (score 19):

The correct instructions to run are :

```
env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE='' dropbox start
```

it worked for me !

The `-i` option is only necessary the first time to install the daemon, but if you've installed *dropbox* with the current user, that's already done.

Comment: this one helped me, is there any way to make it permanent ?
currently am running this command during startup, also its working for other apps too

Comment: Yes, just add another entry in Parameters => Applications then Startup tab ... that's what I did and I don't have to type it anymore.
And of course, you will have to disable the existing dropbox entry.

Answer (score 11):

Dropbox does not recognize Elementary's desktop interface. Therefore, it does not know which icon set to use.

This script has been designed for Elementary OS and I really can recommend it: https://github.com/zant95/elementary-dropbox

Alternatively, you can try running the following commands to use Unity's icon set.

```
dropbox stop

DROPBOX_USE_LIBAPPINDICATOR=1 XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity \
dropbox start -i
```

If this works, you can edit the desktop file located in /usr/share/applications. Open the file with your favourite text editor and change the line `Exec=dropbox start -i` to `Exec=DROPBOX_USE_LIBAPPINDICATOR=1 XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity dropbox start -i`

Got it from here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198977/dropbox-tray-icon-doesnt-show-up-in-elementary-os-luna-freya

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop
```

then replace the exec line to

```
Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE='' dropbox start

dropbox stop

dropbox start -i
```

Comment: Thank you for giving advice how to find and edit the desktop launcher. This was the missing bit in the first answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to add the following two lines in `/usr/bin/dropbox`, just after `import os`:

```
os.environ['XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP']="Unity"
os.environ['QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE']="''"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that the default dropbox script simply copies

`/usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop`

to `$HOME/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop`

So, instead of using the scripts suggested in the answer, simply edit `/usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop`

Change the exec line to:

`Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE='' dropbox start -i`

And then overwrite the autostart file:

`cp /usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop 
$HOME/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop`

Now, logout and login again and the problem is solved, forever. ;)

Comment: If dropbox updates it might overwrite `usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop` back to it's default value.

Comment: I'll be sure to report the upgrade status back here after dropbox upgrades. :)

Answer (score 0):

env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE='' dropbox start
Is the only one that worked but has odd behaviour in Start Applications.
As you can see the env line is shown, then once it successfully runs with correct icon it instantiates a new startup item which even though is disabled for some reason or other wants to run resulting in errant red icon in tray.
[image: Env command before run]
[image: After run Env command]
[image: Next run Env command with errant tray icon]

Comment: The simplest solution from Waldy above seems to work keep the Dropbox startup icon and do away with the env call in startup.