# Dropbox icon missing in Juno

Tags: wingpanel, release-juno, dropbox

Dropbox icon is missing in Juno, and the Loki workarounds ([Dropbox icon missing in Loki](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7550/dropbox-icon-missing-in-loki)) doesn't work anymore.

Comment: i'd tried pure dropbox installation and the workaround working on loki, nothing happened, i'd also tried "elementary-indicators" workaround, now i've franz and skype tray icon working(before not), but dropbox still remain the problem.
no solution found yet :(

Comment: try this (only tested on juno) https://github.com/isneezy/wingpanel-indicator-dropbox

Comment: ok! i've solved! i dont know how, but it works. first i remove all dropbox installation, i remove dropbox-nautilus.
on second thing i'd made, the old loki workaround "elementary-dropbox" uses some iconpacks, so i found the PPA and install all icon-themes(moka, paper, and many more)....
after i restart the "elementary-dropbox" installation without any tray.... i shutdown my laptop, the nex day i poweron it, and tadaaaaa! the magic!
so i think, it is a combination of some iconpack, elementary-dropbox workaround and Wingpanel-indicator-ayatana workaround, thats all

Comment: PS i'd also edited `/usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop`
changing the line Exec like this  
`#Exec=dropbox start -i  `
`Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE='' dropbox start -i  `
that's all id' made.

Comment: PSS this work for 2 users, on my third user dont..... i dont know why.....

Answer (score 3):

Try this workaround from Matt Harris. I've tested with Skype and it works.

https://github.com/mdh34/elementary-indicators

Comment: This did not work for me in Juno. The old answer still works perfectly though: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/32/9

Comment: Update: the old answer no longer works apparently. This is extremely frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

This thing was very annoying to me and I decided to create this simple native wing-panel indicator. It is not perfect but it works very well and I'm still improving, you can try it!

https://github.com/isneezy/wingpanel-indicator-dropbox

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the "problem" is Wingpanel-indicator-ayatana.

see this: 
[Elementary OS 5.0 and Hardware Sensors Indicator](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/17211/elementary-os-5-0-and-hardware-sensors-indicator/17216#17216)

is applicable to almost all wingpanel "problems"

This is because the creators of elementary os think bigger than steam, dropbox, skype, mega, "several famous applications commonly used by users", etc.

Have a nice day.

Comment: correctly identified the issue and (implicitly) provided (a link to) a solution. I came across another answer that does the same thing but in a more concise manner: [Answer for re-enabling missing wing-panel icons](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/17452/how-to-display-system-tray-icons-in-elementary-os-juno)