# How to display system tray icons in elementary OS Juno?

Tags: release-juno

why is the system tray in elementary Juno not like the previous version, in the previous version the system tray can display VLC, RadioTray and others?
is there a way to show the system tray again?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

About system tray icons. In [release-juno](/questions/tagged/release-juno), elementaryOS dropped the support of the old Ayatana Indicators

While the software devs implement the new way you can have them back by...

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yunnxx/elementary
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install indicator-application wingpanel-indicator-ayatana
```

then you need to edit the file `/etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop`, find the line:

```
OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;
```

Add `Pantheon`:

```
OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;Pantheon;
```

Or use sed for a one liner:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;/OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;Pantheon;/g' /etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop
```

Restart X:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Or reboot.

Comment: It doesn't work with ibus, Sebastian :(

Comment: now I see additional icons, it works for me

Comment: I did everything but noting

Comment: Sorry I've missed `OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;Pantheon;` only had `OnlyShowIn=Pantheon;`. Thanks it works like a charm, but the spacing between icons are very large

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: It doesn't work or me

Comment: Did `sudo service lightdm restart` to restart X. That logged me out. When I logged back in my dock disappeared. After a system restart, everything works nicely. Thanks!

Comment: There is a problem with submenus in `yunnxx/elementary` repository `wingpanel-indicator-ayatana` version. To fix this problem you need to install directly from this fork [https://github.com/Lafydev/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana](https://github.com/Lafydev/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana)

Answer (score 5):

the network icon was duplicated, how to leave only what is native to the system?

[image]

Comment: Try this: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21547/double-wi-fi-icon-after-installing-wingpanel-indicator-ayatana