# Double Wi-Fi icon after installing wingpanel-indicator-ayatana

Tags: wingpanel, wifi

After installing wingpanel-indicator-ayatana (available via some answer here) and rebooting, I've got two wi-fi indicators (ss below)
How can I get rid of one of them? Is there any way possible? I don't want to uninstall the indicator app because of dropbox, which I use daily.
[image]

Found [This on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/e8dx1w/duplicate_wifi_indicators_after_enabling_support/), will try it out just appending .old at the end of the name of the file.

Comment: Do you solve your problem if yes it is better if you answer yourself and valide your answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found This on reddit

> > Delete nm-applet from here:
> >
> > /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop

I didn't delete it, just append .old at the end of the filename

Comment: Yes. `sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop-old` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite simple. Run the following commands.

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop
```

Find the following line.

```
NotShowIn=KDE;GNOME;
```

Change it to the following instead.

```
NotShowIn=KDE;GNOME;Pantheon;
```

Then save, and restart. That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this would be to comment out a line in the `nm-applet.desktop` file. In Terminal, do this:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop
```

Then add a `#` to the line that looks like:

```
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=NetworkManager
```

It should now look like:

```
#X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=NetworkManager
```

You will probably need to log out, then log back in before this change is seen.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend disabling it or you might loose some functionality for advanced WiFi settings. Simply edit file `/etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop` and add `--no-indicator` flag in Exec line:

`Exec=nm-applet --no-indicator`.