# Weather in systemtray

Tags: release-hera

Is there any program available that shows the weather in the systemtray?
I mean something like Weather (weather@mockturtl) that you have in linux mint?

Comment: I think this [discussion](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/17453/3460) can help you

Answer (score 2):

You can find it here :
[my weather indicator](https://github.com/atareao/my-weather-indicator)

Comment: I think we can marked this as solved, my weather indicator is the one i was looking for.